# Текст в коллекцию точек

Tags: c#, pdf, text

Всем привет!

В проэкте есть платный pdf viewer котрол, который не может отображать текстовые аннотации. Только чернила, фигуры и перечёркивать, подчёркивать текст.

Необходимо добавить тектсовые аннотации, но контрол их не может отобразить.
Поддержка обещает "в след. версиях" добавить текст. Поэтому было принято решение рисовать програмно текст как чернильную аннотацию, пока нет поддержки отображения текстовой. Но вот как оказалось, не легкая задача переобразовать текст в чернила...

Может кто-то сталкивался или имеет другие идеи как это реализовать?

Comment: Я предлагаю тебе следующее:
1) Сделай копию PDF и измени отдельную аннотацию.
2) Открой оба документа, как текстовые файлы и сравни изменения.

Если они незначительные, то просто самостоятельно напиши простенький парсер и конвертер. Если же необходим хитрый механизм растеризации/векторизации текста, то желаю удачи. Я делал это средствами WinAPI/GDI - получал глифы шрифтов для каждого символа текста, векторизовал надпись, растеризовал после чего вставлял в нужное место, как изображение. Неделя страданий. Лучше посмотреть готовые решения, наверняка найдутся конвертеры.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В конечном итоге, пока SyncFusion не добавит поддердку Free text annotation, рисуем текст как ink annotation.

1. Рисуем фон и добавляем в коллекцию.
2. Рисуем каждый символ отдельно на `bitmap` **фон должен быть прозрачным**.
3. Получаем точки с `bitmap` для `InkAnnotation`.
4. Считаем позицию для каждого символа.
5. Добавляем аннотацию в коллекцию.

   ```
   string text = "Hello world!\nI'm inked text)";
   Font font = new Font("Arial", 32, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);

   PointF textAligment = new PointF(100, 150);

   System.Drawing.Color penColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
   float penOpacity = 1;

   System.Drawing.Color backgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
   float backgroundOpacity = 0.5f;

   Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100);


   List<PdfInkAnnotation> annotations = new List<PdfInkAnnotation>();

   SizeF currentCharSize;
   SizeF prevCharSize;
   SizeF fullTextSize;
   SizeF symbSize;

   PointF curentCharAligment = new PointF(textAligment.X, textAligment.Y + 15);

   BitmapFinder bf = new BitmapFinder();

   //draw ink for every char
   foreach (char symb in text)
   {
       using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
       {
           currentCharSize = gr.MeasureString(symb.ToString(), font);
           fullTextSize = gr.MeasureString(text, font);
           symbSize = gr.MeasureString("A", font);
       }

       if (symb.ToString() == "\n")
       {
           curentCharAligment.X = textAligment.X;
           curentCharAligment.Y += symbSize.Height;
           continue;
       }

       if (symb == ' ')
       {
           curentCharAligment.X += symbSize.Width - symbSize.Width * 0.75f;
           continue;
       }

       #region draw background

       if (annotations.Count == 0)
       {
           float addToBackGroundWidth = 30;

           bitmap = new Bitmap((int)fullTextSize.Width + (int)addToBackGroundWidth, (int)fullTextSize.Height + 20);

           using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
           {
               gr.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
               gr.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(penColor), new RectangleF(0, 0, fullTextSize.Width + addToBackGroundWidth, fullTextSize.Height));
           }

           List<System.Drawing.Point[]> backroundPointsToDrawList = bf.Find(bitmap, false);

           List<System.Drawing.Point> backroundPointsToDraw = new List<System.Drawing.Point>();

           foreach (System.Drawing.Point[] points in backroundPointsToDrawList)
               foreach (System.Drawing.Point point in points)
                   backroundPointsToDraw.Add(new System.Drawing.Point(point.X + (int)curentCharAligment.X, point.Y + (int)curentCharAligment.Y));

           List<float> inkBackgroundPoints = new List<float>();

           foreach (PointF point in backroundPointsToDraw)
           {
               inkBackgroundPoints.Add(converter.ConvertFromPixels(point.X, PdfGraphicsUnit.Point));
               //Y-value is calculated from the bottom of the Pdf page.
               inkBackgroundPoints.Add(converter.ConvertFromPixels(pageHeight, PdfGraphicsUnit.Point) - (converter.ConvertFromPixels(point.Y, PdfGraphicsUnit.Point)));
           }

           PdfInkAnnotation backgroundAnnot = new PdfInkAnnotation(new RectangleF(textAligment.X, textAligment.Y, fullTextSize.Width + 5, fullTextSize.Height + 5), inkBackgroundPoints);
           backgroundAnnot.BorderWidth = 1;
           backgroundAnnot.Opacity = backgroundOpacity;
           backgroundAnnot.Color = new PdfColor(backgroundColor.R, backgroundColor.G, backgroundColor.B);

           annotations.Add(backgroundAnnot);

       }

       #endregion

       bitmap = new Bitmap((int)currentCharSize.Width, (int)currentCharSize.Height);

       using (var gr = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
       {
           gr.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
           gr.DrawString(symb.ToString(), font, new SolidBrush(penColor), new PointF(0, 0));
       }


       List<System.Drawing.Point[]> pointsToDrawList = bf.Find(bitmap, false);

       List<System.Drawing.Point> pointsToDraw = new List<System.Drawing.Point>();

       foreach (System.Drawing.Point[] points in pointsToDrawList)
           foreach (System.Drawing.Point point in points)
               pointsToDraw.Add(new System.Drawing.Point(point.X + (int)curentCharAligment.X, point.Y + (int)curentCharAligment.Y));

       List<float> inkPoints = new List<float>();

       foreach (PointF point in pointsToDraw)
       {
           inkPoints.Add(converter.ConvertFromPixels(point.X, PdfGraphicsUnit.Point));
           //Y-value is calculated from the bottom of the Pdf page.
           inkPoints.Add(converter.ConvertFromPixels(pageHeight, PdfGraphicsUnit.Point) - (converter.ConvertFromPixels(point.Y, PdfGraphicsUnit.Point)));
       }

       PdfInkAnnotation inkAnnot = new PdfInkAnnotation(new RectangleF(curentCharAligment.X, curentCharAligment.Y, currentCharSize.Width, currentCharSize.Height), inkPoints);
       inkAnnot.BorderWidth = 1;
       System.Windows.Media.Color clr = System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(0, 44, 66);
       inkAnnot.Color = new PdfColor(penColor.R, penColor.G, penColor.B);
       inkAnnot.Opacity = penOpacity;

       prevCharSize = currentCharSize;

       curentCharAligment.X += (int)(currentCharSize.Width - currentCharSize.Width * 0.3f);
       //curentCharAligment.Y += (int)currentCharSize.Height;

       annotations.Add(inkAnnot);
   }

   foreach (PdfInkAnnotation annot in annotations)
   {
       ldoc.Pages[0].Annotations.Add(annot);
   }
   ```

Код `BitmapFinder`, спасибо [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9779644/6923381) ответу:

```
public class BitmapFinder
{
int stride = 0;
int[] visited = null;
byte[] bytes = null;
PointData borderdata = null;
Size size = Size.Empty;
Point zeropoint = new Point(-1, -1);

public List<Point[]> Find(Bitmap bmp, bool outside = true)
{
    List<Point> border = new List<Point>();
    BitmapData bmpdata = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    stride = bmpdata.Stride;
    bytes = new byte[bmp.Width * bmp.Height * 4];
    size = bmp.Size;

    Marshal.Copy(bmpdata.Scan0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

    if (!outside)
        borderdata = getData(bytes);
    else
        borderdata = getBorderData(bytes);

    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpdata);

    List<List<Point>> regions = new List<List<Point>>();

    while (borderdata.PointCount > 0)
    {
        List<Point> region = new List<Point>();

        bool valid = true;

        Point startpos = getFirstPoint(borderdata);

        visited = new int[bmp.Size.Width * bmp.Size.Height];

        region.Add(startpos);

        Point current = getNextPoint(startpos);

        if (current != zeropoint)
        {
            visited[current.Y * bmp.Width + current.X]++;
            region.Add(current);
        }

        if (current == zeropoint)
            valid = false;

        while (!current.Equals(startpos) && valid)
        {
            var pos = current;

            if (visited[current.Y * bmp.Width + current.X] < 2)
            {
                current = getNextPoint(pos);
                visited[pos.Y * bmp.Width + pos.X]++;

                if (current == zeropoint)
                    current = getNextPointBackwards(pos);
            }
            else
            {
                current = getNextPointBackwards(pos);
            }

            if (current == zeropoint)
            {
                valid = false;
                break;
            }

            visited[current.Y * bmp.Width + current.X]++;

            region.Add(current);
        }

        foreach (var p in region)
        {
            borderdata.SetPoint(p.Y * bmp.Width + p.X, false);
        }

        if (valid)
            regions.Add(region);
    }

    foreach (var region in regions)
    {
        int duplicatedpos = -1;

        bool[] duplicatecheck = new bool[size.Width * size.Height];
        int length = region.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            var p = region[i];
            if (duplicatecheck[p.Y * size.Width + p.X])
            {
                duplicatedpos = i - 1;
                break;
            }
            duplicatecheck[p.Y * size.Width + p.X] = true;
        }

        if (duplicatedpos == -1)
            continue;

        if (duplicatedpos != ((region.Count - 1) / 2))
            continue;

        bool reversed = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < duplicatedpos; i++)
        {
            if (region[duplicatedpos - i - 1] != region[duplicatedpos + i + 1])
            {
                reversed = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!reversed)
            continue;

        region.RemoveRange(duplicatedpos + 1, region.Count - duplicatedpos - 1);
    }

    List<List<Point>> tempregions = new List<List<Point>>(regions);
    regions.Clear();

    bool connected = true;

    while (connected)
    {
        connected = false;
        foreach (var region in tempregions)
        {
            int connectionpos = -1;
            int connectionregion = -1;
            Point pointstart = region.First();
            Point pointend = region.Last();
            for (int ir = 0; ir < regions.Count; ir++)
            {
                var otherregion = regions[ir];
                if (region == otherregion)
                    continue;

                for (int ip = 0; ip < otherregion.Count; ip++)
                {
                    var p = otherregion[ip];
                    if ((isConnected(pointstart, p) && isConnected(pointend, p)) ||
                        (isConnected(pointstart, p) && isConnected(pointstart, p)))
                    {
                        connectionregion = ir;
                        connectionpos = ip;
                    }

                    if ((isConnected(pointend, p) && isConnected(pointend, p)))
                    {
                        region.Reverse();
                        connectionregion = ir;
                        connectionpos = ip;
                    }
                }

            }

            if (connectionpos == -1)
            {
                regions.Add(region);
            }
            else
            {
                regions[connectionregion].InsertRange(connectionpos, region);
            }

        }

        tempregions = new List<List<Point>>(regions);
        regions.Clear();
    }

    List<Point[]> returnregions = new List<Point[]>();

    foreach (var region in tempregions)
        returnregions.Add(region.ToArray());

    return returnregions;
}

private bool isConnected(Point p0, Point p1)
{

    if (p0.X == p1.X && p0.Y - 1 == p1.Y)
        return true;

    if (p0.X + 1 == p1.X && p0.Y - 1 == p1.Y)
        return true;

    if (p0.X + 1 == p1.X && p0.Y == p1.Y)
        return true;

    if (p0.X + 1 == p1.X && p0.Y + 1 == p1.Y)
        return true;

    if (p0.X == p1.X && p0.Y + 1 == p1.Y)
        return true;

    if (p0.X - 1 == p1.X && p0.Y + 1 == p1.Y)
        return true;

    if (p0.X - 1 == p1.X && p0.Y == p1.Y)
        return true;

    if (p0.X - 1 == p1.X && p0.Y - 1 == p1.Y)
        return true;

    return false;
}

private Point getNextPoint(Point pos)
{
    if (pos.Y > 0)
    {
        int x = pos.X;
        int y = pos.Y - 1;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    if (pos.Y > 0 && pos.X < size.Width - 1)
    {
        int x = pos.X + 1;
        int y = pos.Y - 1;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    if (pos.X < size.Width - 1)
    {
        int x = pos.X + 1;
        int y = pos.Y;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    if (pos.X < size.Width - 1 && pos.Y < size.Height - 1)
    {
        int x = pos.X + 1;
        int y = pos.Y + 1;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    if (pos.Y < size.Height - 1)
    {
        int x = pos.X;
        int y = pos.Y + 1;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }


    if (pos.Y < size.Height - 1 && pos.X > 0)
    {
        int x = pos.X - 1;
        int y = pos.Y + 1;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    if (pos.X > 0)
    {
        int x = pos.X - 1;
        int y = pos.Y;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }

    if (pos.X > 0 && pos.Y > 0)
    {
        int x = pos.X - 1;
        int y = pos.Y - 1;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
        }
    }


    return zeropoint;
}

private Point getNextPointBackwards(Point pos)
{
    Point backpoint = zeropoint;

    int trys = 0;

    if (pos.X > 0 && pos.Y > 0)
    {
        int x = pos.X - 1;
        int y = pos.Y - 1;
        if (ValidPoint(x, y) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
            if (backpoint == zeropoint || trys > visited[y * size.Width + x])
            {
                backpoint = new Point(x, y);
                trys = visited[y * size.Width + x];
            }
        }
    }

    if (pos.X > 0)
    {
        int x = pos.X - 1;
        int y = pos.Y;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
            if (backpoint == zeropoint || trys > visited[y * size.Width + x])
            {
                backpoint = new Point(x, y);
                trys = visited[y * size.Width + x];
            }
        }
    }

    if (pos.Y < size.Height - 1 && pos.X > 0)
    {
        int x = pos.X - 1;
        int y = pos.Y + 1;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
            if (backpoint == zeropoint || trys > visited[y * size.Width + x])
            {
                backpoint = new Point(x, y);
                trys = visited[y * size.Width + x];
            }
        }
    }

    if (pos.Y < size.Height - 1)
    {
        int x = pos.X;
        int y = pos.Y + 1;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
            if (backpoint == zeropoint || trys > visited[y * size.Width + x])
            {
                backpoint = new Point(x, y);
                trys = visited[y * size.Width + x];
            }
        }
    }


    if (pos.X < size.Width - 1 && pos.Y < size.Height - 1)
    {
        int x = pos.X + 1;
        int y = pos.Y + 1;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
            if (backpoint == zeropoint || trys > visited[y * size.Width + x])
            {
                backpoint = new Point(x, y);
                trys = visited[y * size.Width + x];
            }
        }
    }


    if (pos.X < size.Width - 1)
    {
        int x = pos.X + 1;
        int y = pos.Y;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
            if (backpoint == zeropoint || trys > visited[y * size.Width + x])
            {
                backpoint = new Point(x, y);
                trys = visited[y * size.Width + x];
            }
        }
    }

    if (pos.Y > 0 && pos.X < size.Width - 1)
    {
        int x = pos.X + 1;
        int y = pos.Y - 1;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
            if (backpoint == zeropoint || trys > visited[y * size.Width + x])
            {
                backpoint = new Point(x, y);
                trys = visited[y * size.Width + x];
            }
        }
    }


    if (pos.Y > 0)
    {
        int x = pos.X;
        int y = pos.Y - 1;
        if ((ValidPoint(x, y)) && HasNeighbor(x, y))
        {
            if (visited[y * size.Width + x] == 0)
            {
                return new Point(x, y);
            }
            if (backpoint == zeropoint || trys > visited[y * size.Width + x])
            {
                backpoint = new Point(x, y);
                trys = visited[y * size.Width + x];
            }
        }
    }

    return backpoint;
}

private bool ValidPoint(int x, int y)
{
    return (borderdata[y * size.Width + x]);
}

private bool HasNeighbor(int x, int y)
{
    if (y > 0)
    {
        if (!borderdata[(y - 1) * size.Width + x])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (ValidPoint(x, y))
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (x < size.Width - 1)
    {
        if (!borderdata[y * size.Width + (x + 1)])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (ValidPoint(x, y))
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (y < size.Height - 1)
    {
        if (!borderdata[(y + 1) * size.Width + x])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (ValidPoint(x, y))
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (x > 0)
    {
        if (!borderdata[y * size.Width + (x - 1)])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else if (ValidPoint(x, y))
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

private Point getFirstPoint(PointData data)
{
    Point startpos = zeropoint;
    for (int y = 0; y < size.Height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < size.Width; x++)
        {
            if (data[y * size.Width + x])
            {
                startpos = new Point(x, y);
                return startpos;
            }
        }
    }
    return startpos;
}

private PointData getBorderData(byte[] bytes)
{
    PointData isborderpoint = new PointData(size.Height * size.Width);
    bool prevtrans = false;
    bool currenttrans = false;
    for (int y = 0; y < size.Height; y++)
    {
        prevtrans = false;
        for (int x = 0; x <= size.Width; x++)
        {
            if (x == size.Width)
            {
                if (!prevtrans)
                {
                    isborderpoint.SetPoint(y * size.Width + x - 1, true);
                }
                continue;
            }
            currenttrans = bytes[y * stride + x * 4 + 3] == 0;
            if (x == 0 && !currenttrans)
                isborderpoint.SetPoint(y * size.Width + x, true);
            if (prevtrans && !currenttrans)
                isborderpoint.SetPoint(y * size.Width + x - 1, true);
            if (!prevtrans && currenttrans && x != 0)
                isborderpoint.SetPoint(y * size.Width + x, true);
            prevtrans = currenttrans;
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < size.Width; x++)
    {
        prevtrans = false;
        for (int y = 0; y <= size.Height; y++)
        {
            if (y == size.Height)
            {
                if (!prevtrans)
                {
                    isborderpoint.SetPoint((y - 1) * size.Width + x, true);
                }
                continue;
            }
            currenttrans = bytes[y * stride + x * 4 + 3] == 0;
            if (y == 0 && !currenttrans)
                isborderpoint.SetPoint(y * size.Width + x, true);
            if (prevtrans && !currenttrans)
                isborderpoint.SetPoint((y - 1) * size.Width + x, true);
            if (!prevtrans && currenttrans && y != 0)
                isborderpoint.SetPoint(y * size.Width + x, true);
            prevtrans = currenttrans;
        }
    }
    return isborderpoint;
}

private PointData getData(byte[] bytes)
{
    PointData isborderpoint = new PointData(size.Height * size.Width);
    bool prevtrans = false;
    bool currenttrans = false;
    for (int y = 0; y < size.Height; y++)
    {
        prevtrans = false;
        for (int x = 0; x <= size.Width; x++)
        {
            if (x == size.Width)
            {
                if (!prevtrans)
                {
                    isborderpoint.SetPoint(y * size.Width + x - 1, true);
                }
                continue;
            }
            currenttrans = bytes[y * stride + x * 4 + 3] == 0;

            if (!currenttrans)
                isborderpoint.SetPoint(y * size.Width + x, true);

            prevtrans = currenttrans;
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < size.Width; x++)
    {
        prevtrans = false;
        for (int y = 0; y <= size.Height; y++)
        {
            if (y == size.Height)
            {
                if (!prevtrans)
                {
                    isborderpoint.SetPoint((y - 1) * size.Width + x, true);
                }
                continue;
            }
            currenttrans = bytes[y * stride + x * 4 + 3] == 0;

            if (!currenttrans)
                isborderpoint.SetPoint(y * size.Width + x, true);

            prevtrans = currenttrans;
        }
    }
    return isborderpoint;
}
}
```

[image: результат]